# Advise for two non gaussian distribution group

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design, kruskal-wallis-test

I have a dataset which test the introduction of a new measure of a luggage checking a local small airport, the aim is to conclude whether the new measure reduce the luggage checking time.

My dataset is quite simple and looks like that [please not that the time interval between observation is irregular].

```
TimeCheckLuggage  Type
===================================
20                 BeforeMeasure
20                 BeforeMeasure
30                 BeforeMeasure
18                 AfterMeasure
17                 AfterMeasure
18                 AfterMeasure
```

So it means that for the first five days all passenger had same treatment (old style of luggage checking) and the last five days all passenger had the same treatment (new style of checking luggage). Maybe is not the best design, but I cannot change it.

When I plot the 2 distribution [before versus after measure] on a density plot or histogram it looks non gaussian. I cannot show the data. But I draw a sketch of how the density looks like [I just draw the sketch for 1 distribution but the second looks quit similar]:

[image]

So my question is what would be the best way (test or other) to answer my question? Would something like a Kruskal-Wallis test be ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two groups a one-sided two-sample Wilcoxon (rank sum) test may be appropriate. (Kruskal-Wallis accommodates more than two groups. Also, in view of the long right tails, I wonder if a Welch t test would be appropriate.)

Are the long right tails a particular problem? Such as passengers arriving at destinations without baggage? If so you may want to do a separate test to see if the new style of checking makes that problem worse. (Perhaps counts in a $2 \times 2$ table, leading to a Fisher Exact test.)

Puzzled by: "Please note that the time interval between observation is irregular." Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Thanks, it helps.  PS: I have to investigate more regarding your question I do not know yet.